# Encode raw transaction data for inner transaction data for transfer using erc223

Tags: solidity, bytes, encoding

How do I encode data for inner transaction call of ERC223Receiver contract after transferring erc223 tokens to it?

example:

```
Contract ERC223Receiver {
    function foo(uint256 a) {
        // some work
    }
}


Contract Other {
    function bar(address token, address receiver, uint256 amount, uint256 a) {
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(sha3("foo(uint256)"));

        bytes data = bytes(sig + a) // ????

        token.transfer(receiver, amount, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: The scenario you are describing is closer to ERC827, not ERC223. ERC223 expects 'tokenFallback' function on the receiving end, and calls it passing the argument data, no need to package the function signature itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out using assembly:

```
Contract Other {
    function bar(address token, address receiver, uint256 amount, uint256 a) {
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(sha3("foo(uint256)"));
        uint256 argsSize = 1 * 32;
        // sig + arguments size
        uint256 dataSize = 4 + argsSize;

        bytes memory m_data = new bytes(dataSize);

        assembly {
            // Add the signature first to memory
            mstore(add(m_data, 0x20), sig)
            // Add the parameters
            mstore(add(m_data, 0x24), a)
        }

        token.transfer(receiver, amount, m_data);
    }
}
```